# Parent And Child In Css

Tags: html, css

Can an id be a parent in CSS? For example:

```
<div id="link">
    </a href="www.example.com"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
link > a{ 
    /* style goes here*/
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: `#link > a` is possible

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect. Your opening `a` tag is actually a closing tag.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah it was a typo :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect. Your opening `a` tag is actually a closing tag. And your `a` element has no content to click on.

Beyond that, just use the **["child" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** on any valid selector: `parent > child`.

**It doesn't matter what kind of selector `parent` and `child` are (element, id, class, pseudo-class, pseudo-element, hierarchical, etc.) as long as they are valid.**

```css
#parent {
  height:100px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255,.2);
  padding:20px;
}

/* This will select all <a> elements that are children of #parent */
#parent > a { 
    background-color:yellow;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(75,75,0,.8);
    padding:5px;
    margin:2px;
    border-radius:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}

/* This will affect any <a> that is being interactied with */
#parent > a:active { 
    background-color:yellow;
    box-shadow:-2px -2px 2px rgba(100,100,100,.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click me</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click me</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click me</a>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">Click me</a>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

```
#link >a{
 color:red;
}
```

```css
#link >a{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="link"><a href="www.example.com">LINK</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: system-ui;
            user-select: none;
        }
        
        #game {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 70%;
            min-height: 150px;
            min-width: 300px;
            padding: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
            background-color: rgba(207, 138, 70);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #game-end {
            position: absolute;
            width: 250px;
            height: 150px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: rgba(207, 138, 70, 0.99);
            padding: 40px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .end-text {
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        .no-display {
            visibility: hidden;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .hidden {
            color: transparent;
        }
        .secret-character {
            margin: 3px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .secret-character-border {
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        .character {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .game-inactive {
            opacity: 0.1;
        }
        #guessed-characters {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            min-height: 25px;
        }
        #secret-word {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        #remaining-guesses-container {
            display: flex;
            top: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        #remaining-guesses {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
        button {
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            background-color: brown;
            color:white;
        }
        button:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #game-message {
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 2px white solid;
            padding: 10px;
            min-height: 18px;
            width: 80%;
        }
        #person {
            font-size: 25px;
            height: 186px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #torso, #lower {
            display: flex;
        }
        #head {
            font-size: 40;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }
        #torso {
            font-size: 35px;
            top: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            left: -1px;
        }
        #arm-left {
            margin-top: 2px;
            margin-right: -5;
        }
        #arm-right {
            margin-left: -5;
            margin-top: 2px;
        }
        #lower {
            font-size: 35px;
            top: 60px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -24px;
        }
        .intact {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #pole {
            border-right: 7px solid brown;
            border-top: 7px solid brown;
            width: 80px;
            height: 138px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 178px;
            top: 137px;
        }
        #rope {
            position: absolute;
            top: 129px;
            right: 233px;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
        #game-unstarted {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding: 35px;
            border: 3px solid black;
            background-color: orangered;
        }
        #game-started {
            position: relative;
            align-items: center;
            width: 500;
            height: 500;
        }
        #singleplayer, #multiplayer {
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 25px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="game-unstarted">
            <button id="singleplayer">
                One-player
            </button>
            <button id="multiplayer">
                Two-player
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="game-started" class="no-display">
            <div id="props">
                <div>
                    <div id="rope">
                        |
                    </div>
                    <div id="pole">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="person"> <!--these are the body parts for the person-->
                    <div id="head" class="appendage intact">
                        o
                    </div>
                    <div id="torso">
                        <div id="arm-left" class="appendage intact">
                            /
                        </div>
                        <div id="body" class="appendage intact">
                            |
                        </div>
                        <div id="arm-right" class="appendage intact">
                            \
                        </div>
                    </div>               
                    <div id="lower">
                        <div id="leg-left" class="appendage intact">
                            /
                        </div>
                        <div id="leg-right" class="appendage intact">
                            \
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="game">
                <div id="guessed-characters">
                </div>
                <div id="secret-word">
                </div>
                <div id="game-message">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="game-end" class="no-display">
                <div id="game-end-message" class="end-text">
                </div>
                <div id="revealed-secret" class="end-text">
                </div>
                <button id="restart-game" class="end-text">
                    Play again
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function includes(char, string) { 
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                var currentStrChar = string[i];
                if (char === currentStrChar) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };
        function createDivWithText(text) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = text;
            return div;
        };
        function getRandomEntry(array) {
            var randomIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
            return array[randomIdx];
        };
        function Hangman(secretWord) {
            this.originalGameState = document.body.innerHTML;
            this.secretWord = secretWord;
            this.charactersGuessed = '';
            this.remainingBadGuesses = 6;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.initializeSecretWord = function() {
            var container = document.getElementById('secret-word');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length; i++) {
                var secretChar = this.secretWord[i];
                var div = createDivWithText(secretChar);
                div.classList.add('secret-character', 'hidden');
                container.append(div);
            }
        };
        Hangman.prototype.revealBodyPart = function() {
            this.remainingBadGuesses -= 1;
            function reveal(id) {
                var container = document.getElementById(id);
                container.classList.remove("intact"); 
            }
            if (this.remainingBadGuesses === 5) {
                reveal("head");
            }
            else if (this.remainingBadGuesses === 4) {
                reveal("body");
            }
            else if (this.remainingBadGuesses === 3) {
                reveal("arm-left");
            }
            else if (this.remainingBadGuesses === 2) {
                reveal("arm-right");
            }
            else if (this.remainingBadGuesses === 1) {
                reveal("leg-left");
            }
        };
        Hangman.prototype.playerLost = function() {
            return this.remainingBadGuesses === 0;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.showGameEnd = function() {
            var gameContainer = document.getElementById('game');
            gameContainer.classList.add('game-inactive');
            var hangmanContainer = document.getElementById('props');
            hangmanContainer.classList.add('game-inactive');
            var gameEndContainer = document.getElementById('game-end');
            gameEndContainer.classList.remove('no-display');
            var messageContainer = document.getElementById('game-end-message');
            if (this.playerLost()) {
                messageContainer.innerHTML = "You Lose!";
            }
            else {
                messageContainer.innerHTML = "You Win!";
            }
            var secretContainer = document.getElementById('revealed-secret');
            secretContainer.innerHTML = 'The secret was: ' + this.secretWord;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.playerWon = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length; i++) {
                var secretChar = this.secretWord[i];
                if (!includes(secretChar, this.charactersGuessed)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true
        };
        Hangman.prototype.addToCharactersGuessed = function(char) {
            this.charactersGuessed += char;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.appendGuessedCharacter = function(key) {
            var guessedCharDiv = createDivWithText(key);
            guessedCharDiv.classList.add('character')
            var container = document.getElementById('guessed-characters');
            container.append(guessedCharDiv);
        };
        Hangman.prototype.updateSecretCharacter = function(char) {
            var allSecretChars = document.getElementsByClassName('secret-character');
            for (var i = 0; i < allSecretChars.length; i++) {
                var secretChar = allSecretChars[i];
                if (char.toLowerCase() === secretChar.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    secretChar.classList.remove("hidden");
                }
            }
                
        };
        Hangman.prototype.resetGameState = function() {
            document.body.innerHTML = this.originalGameState;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.initializeSecretWord = function() {
            var container = document.getElementById("secret-word");
            for (var i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length; i++) {
                var secretChar = this.secretWord[i];
                var div = createDivWithText(secretChar);
                div.classList.add('secret-character', 'hidden');
                container.append(div);
            }
        };
        Hangman.prototype.alreadyGuessed = function(guessedKey) {
            return includes(guessedKey, this.charactersGuessed);
        };
        Hangman.prototype.isInvalidGuess = function(guessedKey) {
            var isAlphabetic = includes(guessedKey, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
            return !isAlphabetic;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.updateGameMessage = function(msg) {
            var messageContainer = document.getElementById('game-message');
            messageContainer.innerHTML = msg;
        };
        Hangman.prototype.clearGameMessage = function() {
            var messageContainer = document.getElementById('game-message');
        };
        Hangman.prototype.correctGuess = function(guessedKey) {
            return includes(guessedKey, this.secretWord);
        };
        function initialize() {
            var modeChosen = false
            var wordBank = ["grass", "tree", "boat", "house", "thing", "coding", "computer", 
            "leaves", "food", "chair", "dog", "cat", "tiger", "ninja", "snake", "rabbit", "wall", "book",
            "notebook", "math", "science", "programming", "plant", "hummingbird", "game", "basketball", "soccer", "football", 
            "tennis", 'read', "mouse", "rat", "globe", "poster", "fraction", "multiplication", "cards", "board", "plank",
            "shorts", "pants", "jacket", "socks", "plane", "bear", "chicken", "rooster", "ball", "soccerball", "green", "red", "purple", "blue", "orange",
            "ant", "baboon", "badger", "wolf", "python", "fox", "goat", "panda", "shark", "hawk", "seal", "beaver", "toad",
            "rhino", "owl", "otter", "lion", "hole", "floor", "flood", "drought", "tsnuami", "banana", "city", "anger", "happiness",
            "family", "glass", "grass", "dirt", "stone", "needle", "key", "hangman", "word", "fate", "magic", "spell", "magician", "chart", "stuff", 
            "fence", "flower", "cord", "fan", "clock", "father", "mother", "brother", "sister", "aunt", "uncle", "grandfather", "grandmother", 
            "teacher", "school", "box", "feline", "moose", "antler", "horn", "biology", "chemistry", "physics", "division", "fur", "coat", "paws", 
            "binder", "battery", "circuit", "electricity", "gravity", "universe", "galexy", "world", "paper", "pencil", "container", "root",
            "pi", "gnat"];
            var randomWord = getRandomEntry(wordBank);
            var game = new Hangman(randomWord); 
            game.initializeSecretWord(); 
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                if (modeChosen) {
                    if (game.playerWon() || game.playerLost()) {
                    return;  
                }
                var guessedKey = event.key.toLowerCase();
                if (game.isInvalidGuess(guessedKey)) {
                    return;  
                }
                if (game.alreadyGuessed(guessedKey)) {
                    game.updateGameMessage('You already guessed ' + guessedKey);
                    return; 
                }
               
                game.addToCharactersGuessed(guessedKey);
                game.appendGuessedCharacter(guessedKey);
                if (game.correctGuess(guessedKey)) {
                    game.updateGameMessage('Yes! The secret contains ' + guessedKey);
                    game.updateSecretCharacter(guessedKey);
                }
                else {
                    game.updateGameMessage('Nope, the secret does not have a ' + guessedKey);
                    game.revealBodyPart();
                }
                if (game.playerWon() || game.playerLost()) {
                    game.showGameEnd();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                return;
            }
            });
            
            var singleplayerButton = document.getElementById('singleplayer');
            singleplayerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var gameDivs = document.getElementById('game-started');
                gameDivs.classList.remove('no-display');
                var setupDivs = document.getElementById('game-unstarted');
                setupDivs.classList.add('no-display');
                modeChosen = true;
                return;
            });
            
            var multiplayerButton = document.getElementById('multiplayer');
            multiplayerButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                var gameDivs = document.getElementById('game-started');
                gameDivs.classList.remove('no-display');
                var setupDivs = document.getElementById('game-unstarted');
                setupDivs.classList.add('no-display');
                modeChosen = true;
                return;
            });
                
            var playAgainButton = document.getElementById('restart-game');
            playAgainButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                game.resetGameState();
                initialize(); 
            });
        };
        initialize(); 
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).